# Dequeue script in template isn't working

Tags: functions, theme-development, templates, wp-enqueue-script

I want to dequeue a script ('enterprise-responsive-menu'), but the function I have in my template does not do that. Does anything look wrong?

Here is the enqueue in functions.php-

```
//* Enqueue Scripts 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enterprise_load_scripts' );
function enterprise_load_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'enterprise-responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700,300italic|Titillium+Web:600', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION ); 
}'
```

Here is the dequeue code in my template -

```
//Remove Mobile Header
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
wp_dequeue_script( 'enterprise-responsive-menu' );
wp_deregister_script( 'enterprise-responsive-menu' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

Comment: Why are you deregistering the script when you can simply not register it to begin with? I sense there is missing information here, please provide more context about where the code is located, including which file your dequeue code is located in

Comment: @Tom,
The script is enqueued in functions.php, meaning it is global and applied to every template. I don't want to remove it globally, but I need to deactivate it on a specific page template. Does this clarify my question a little better? 

goto10 provided a solution that I believe will work. I'm going to try implementing tomorrow.

Comment: So your dequeue scripts hook is **not** in functions.php? It's in a page template? Where in the file is it? The timing/when it's added is important

Comment: Ya, I was vaguely aware the importance of placement, but I thought I had it in the right spot. However, I have found out I only need to run the script I wanted to dequeue on one page template, so my best bet is to just place a conditional statement in the functions.php that only enqueues the script on a specific page template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts()` function to your `functions.php` file and add a conditional statement to determine if the appropriate template is being loaded. E.g.:

```
// Remove Mobile Header
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'name-of-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'enterprise-responsive-menu' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'enterprise-responsive-menu' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

I suspect that your function is not working because it has been placed somewhere after the call to `get_header()` in the template file which means it would be too late to dequeue the script. Declaring functions in template files is not a good practice anyway, so use your `functions.php` file or another include.

Comment: Thanks Dave! This was exactly the help that I needed. Also, very quick to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enterprise_load_scripts' );
function enterprise_load_scripts(){
    if ( !is_page_template( 'name-of-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'enterprise-responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    }
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700,300italic|Titillium+Web:600', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION ); 
}
```

Instead of dequeue, what if you put that specific script in a condition so that it loads only on pages with any template except those where you don't want to..